# Operation sharing in mathematical expressions

Tags: optimization

I have a set of mathematical expressions (only contains sum (+) operation). Here is an example:

$$E1= a+b+c$$
$$E2= a+b+d$$
$$E3= a+b+c+e$$
$$E4= a+b+d+f$$

I want to know if there is a method or algorithm to compute these expressions by using the minimum number of operations. So that for my example:

$$R1=a+b+c$$
$$R2=R1-c+d$$
$$R3=R1+e$$
$$R4=R2+f$$

In this example, computing each expression separately needs 10 operations, but by reusing the repeated parts we will find all results with 6 operations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707389/how-can-i-minimise-number-of-additions), how to add things *hierarchically*. This could already be helpful.

Comment: See also [addition chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_chain) which is similar.